# How to vertically top-align `align`-environments inside `\item`s when using `multicol`?

Tags: align, enumerate, multicol, enumitem

As shown in the attached figure, The solution-part has a lot of vertical space and seems that the `align*` environments are vertical aligned on center. I want to avoid getting these vertical white spaces, and align them on top. How to do so? Any suggestions are welcome!

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol,amsmath,enumitem,lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper,marginparwidth=3cm,innermargin=1cm,outermargin=4.3cm,marginparsep=3mm,]{geometry}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\section*{Problem}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
    \item $\displaystyle \frac{\left(2a\right)^3 3a^\frac13}{a^{-\frac23}6a^2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \frac{\left(-b^3\right)^2\left(a^\frac14\right)^{-3}b^3}{\left(a^2\right)^4b^\frac14}$
    \item $\displaystyle \left(\frac{-2a^3b^{-4}}{5a^{-5}b^{-6}}\right)^{-2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \left(\frac{9x^{-2}y^\frac13}{4x^\frac12 y^{-\frac34}}\right)^\frac32$
    \item $\displaystyle \left(\frac{a^\frac12b^{-3}}{a^{-1}b^{-\frac32}}\right)^\frac23$
    \item $\displaystyle \left(\frac{a^{-4}b^2c}{ab^{-6}c^3}\right)^4$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\section*{Solution}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
    \item 
        \begin{align*}
            \frac{\left(2a\right)^3 3a^\frac13}{a^{-\frac23}6a^2}
            &= \frac{2^3 \cdot a^3 \cdot 3^1 \cdot a^\frac13}{2^1 \cdot 3^1 \cdot a^{-\frac23}\cdot a^2}\\
            &= 2^{3-1} \cdot 3^{1-1} \cdot a^{3+\frac13-\left(-\frac23\right)-2}\\
            &= 2^2 \cdot 3^0 \cdot a^2\\
            &= 2^2 \cdot 1 \cdot a^2\\
            &= 2^2 \cdot a^2
        \end{align*}
    \item
        \begin{align*}
            \frac{\left(-b^3\right)^2\left(a^\frac14\right)^{-3}b^3}{\left(a^2\right)^4b^\frac14}
            &= \frac{(-1)^2\cdot b^{3\cdot 2} \cdot a^{\frac14\cdot(-3)}\cdot b^3}{a^{2\cdot 4}\cdot b^\frac14}\\
            &= \frac{1\cdot b^6 \cdot a^{-\frac34}\cdot b^3}{a^8 \cdot b^\frac14}\\
            &= \frac{b^{6+3-\frac14}}{a^{8-\left(-\frac34\right)}} \\
            &= \frac{b^{8\frac34}}{a^{8\frac34}}
        \end{align*}
    \item 
        \begin{align*}
            \left(\frac{-2a^3b^{-4}}{5a^{-5}b^{-6}}\right)^{-2}
            &= \frac{(-1)^{-2} \cdot (2)^{-2}\cdot a^{3\cdot(-2)} \cdot b^{-4\cdot(-2)}}{5^{-2}\cdot a^{-5\cdot (-2)}\cdot b^{-6\cdot (-2)}}\\
            &= \frac{1 \cdot 2^{-2}\cdot a^{-6} \cdot b^8}{5^{-2}\cdot a^{10}\cdot b^{12}}\\
            &= \frac{5^2 }{2^2 \cdot a^{10-(-6)}\cdot b^{12-8}}\\
            &= \frac{5^2 }{2^2 \cdot a^{16}\cdot b^4}
        \end{align*}
    \item
        \begin{align*}
            \left(\frac{9x^{-2}y^\frac13}{4x^\frac12 y^{-\frac34}}\right)^\frac32
            &= \frac{(3^2)^\frac32 \cdot x^{-2\cdot \frac32} \cdot y^{\frac13\cdot \frac32}}{(2^2)^\frac32 \cdot x^{\frac12\cdot\frac32}\cdot y^{-\frac34\cdot \frac32}}\\
            &= \frac{3^3 \cdot x^{-3} \cdot y^\frac12}{2^3 \cdot x^\frac34\cdot y^{-\frac98}}\\
            &= \frac{3^3 \cdot y^{\frac12-\left(-\frac98\right)}}{2^3 \cdot x^{\frac34-(-3)}}\\
            &= \frac{3^3 \cdot y^\frac{13}8}{2^3 \cdot x^\frac{15}4}
        \end{align*}
    \item
        \begin{align*}
            \left(\frac{a^\frac12b^{-3}}{a^{-1}b^{-\frac32}}\right)^\frac23
            &= \frac{a^{\frac12\cdot\frac23}\cdot b^{-3\cdot \frac23}}{a^{-1\cdot\frac23} \cdot b^{-\frac32 \cdot \frac23}}\\
            &= \frac{a^\frac13\cdot b^{-2}}{a^{-\frac23} \cdot b^{-1}}\\
            &= \frac{a^{\frac13-\left(-\frac23\right)}}{b^{-1-(-2)}}\\
            &= \frac{a}{b}
        \end{align*}
    \item
        \begin{align*}
            \left(\frac{a^{-4}b^2c}{ab^{-6}c^3}\right)^4
            &= \frac{a^{-4\cdot 4}\cdot b^{2\cdot 4}\cdot c^{1\cdot4}}{a^{1\cdot4}\cdot b^{-6\cdot4}\cdot c^{3\cdot4}}\\
            &= \frac{a^{-16}\cdot b^8 \cdot c^4}{a^4 \cdot b^{-24}\cdot c^{12}}\\
            &= \frac{b^{8-(-24)}}{a^{4-(-16)} \cdot c^{12-4}}\\
            &= \frac{b^{32}}{a^{20} \cdot c^8}
        \end{align*}
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Backticks in the title are not useful!

Comment: They don't do anything formatting wise, but it helps distinguish the two meanings of align. However, feel free to remove them if you think it makes your question more unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the `tasks` environment, which is better suited for what you want than an `enumerate` environment in a `multicols`:  the item s (called `\task`) wil be displayed horizontally, and in case of an equation overflowing into the next column, `\task*\ let is spread over both.Also, I replaced`amsmath`with its extension`mathtools`because I needed its`\MoveEqLeft` command for some alignments.

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, enumitem,lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper, marginparwidth=3cm, innermargin=1cm, outermargin=4.3cm, marginparsep=3mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mleftright, tasks} 


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\section*{Problem}

\begin{tasks}[counter-format=tsk[a].](2)
    \task $\displaystyle \frac{\left(2a\right)^3 3a^\frac13}{a^{-\frac23}6a^2}$
    \task $\displaystyle \frac{\left(-b^3\right)^2\bigl(a^\frac14\bigr)^{\!-3}b^3}{\left(a^2\right)^4b^\frac14}$
    \task $\displaystyle \left(\frac{-2a^3b^{-4}}{5a^{-5}b^{-6}}\right)^{\!\!-2}$
    \task $\displaystyle \mleft(\frac{9x^{-2}y^{\smash{\frac13}}}{4x^\frac12 y^{-\frac34}}\mright)^{\!\!\frac32}$
    \task $\displaystyle \mleft(\frac{a^{\smash{\frac12}}b^{-3}}{a^{-1}b^{-\frac32}}\mright)^{\!\!\frac23}$
    \task $\displaystyle \left(\frac{a^{-4}b^2c}{ab^{-6}c^3}\right)^{\!\!4}$
\end{tasks}

\section*{Solution}

\begin{tasks}[counter-format=tsk[a].](2)%[label=\alph*.]
    \task
       $ \begin{aligned}[t]
            \frac{\left(2a\right)^3 3a^\frac13}{a^{-\frac23}6a^2}
            &= \frac{2^3 \cdot a^3 \cdot 3^1 \cdot a^\frac13}{2^1 \cdot 3^1 \cdot a^{-\frac23}\cdot a^2}\\
            &= 2^{3-1} \cdot 3^{1-1} \cdot a^{3+\frac13-\left(-\frac23\right)-2}\\
            &= 2^2 \cdot 3^0 \cdot a^2
            = 2^2 \cdot 1 \cdot a^2\\
            &= 2^2 \cdot a^2
        \end{aligned} $
    \task
       $ \begin{aligned}[t]
           \MoveEqLeft[1] \frac{\left(-b^3\right)^2\bigl(a^\frac14\bigr)^{\!-3}b^3}{\left(a^2\right)^4b^\frac14}\\
            &= \frac{(-1)^2\cdot b^{3\cdot 2} \cdot a^{\frac14\cdot(-3)}\cdot b^3}{a^{2\cdot 4}\cdot b^\frac14}\\
            &= \frac{1\cdot b^6 \cdot a^{-\frac34}\cdot b^3}{a^8 \cdot b^\frac14}= \frac{b^{6+3-\frac14}}{a^{8-\left(-\frac34\right)}}= \frac{b^{8\frac34}}{a^{8\frac34}}
        \end{aligned} $
    \task*
        $ \begin{aligned}[t]%
            \left(\frac{-2a^3b^{-4}}{5a^{-5}b^{-6}}\right)^{\!\!-2}
            &= \frac{(-1)^{-2} \cdot (2)^{-2}\cdot a^{3\cdot(-2)} \cdot b^{-4\cdot(-2)}}{5^{-2}\cdot a^{-5\cdot (-2)}\cdot b^{-6\cdot (-2)}}
            = \frac{1 \cdot 2^{-2}\cdot a^{-6} \cdot b^8}{5^{-2}\cdot a^{10}\cdot b^{12}}\\
            &= \frac{5^2 }{2^2 \cdot a^{10-(-6)}\cdot b^{12-8}}
            = \frac{5^2 }{2^2 \cdot a^{16}\cdot b^4}
        \end{aligned} $
    \task
        $ \begin{aligned}[t]
            \MoveEqLeft \mleft(\frac{9x^{-2}y^{\smash{\frac13}}}{4x^\frac12 y^{-\frac34}}\mright)^{\!\!\frac32}
            = \frac{(3^2)^\frac32 \cdot x^{-2\cdot \frac32} \cdot y^{\frac13\cdot \frac32}}{(2^2)^\frac32 \cdot x^{\frac12\cdot\frac32}\cdot y^{-\frac34\cdot \frac32}}\\
            &= \frac{3^3 \cdot x^{-3} \cdot y^\frac12}{2^3 \cdot x^\frac34\cdot y^{-\frac98}}
            = \frac{3^3 \cdot y^{\frac12-\left(-\frac98\right)}}{2^3 \cdot x^{\frac34-(-3)}}\\
            &= \frac{3^3 \cdot y^\frac{13}8}{2^3 \cdot x^\frac{15}4}
        \end{aligned} $
    \task
        $ \begin{aligned}[t]
          \MoveEqLeft \mleft(\frac{a^{\smash{\frac12}}b^{-3}}{a^{-1}b^{-\frac32}}\mright)^{\!\!\frac23}
            = \frac{a^{\frac12\cdot\frac23}\cdot b^{-3\cdot \frac23}}{a^{-1\cdot\frac23} \cdot b^{-\frac32 \cdot \frac23}}\\
            &= \frac{a^\frac13\cdot b^{-2}}{a^{-\frac23} \cdot b^{-1}}
            = \frac{a^{\frac13-\left(-\frac23\right)}}{b^{-1-(-2)}}
            = \frac{a}{b}
        \end{aligned} $
    \task*
        $ \begin{aligned}[t]
            \left(\frac{a^{-4}b^2c}{ab^{-6}c^3}\right)^{\!\!4}
            &= \frac{a^{-4\cdot 4}\cdot b^{2\cdot 4}\cdot c^{1\cdot4}}{a^{1\cdot4}\cdot b^{-6\cdot4}\cdot c^{3\cdot4}}
            = \frac{a^{-16}\cdot b^8 \cdot c^4}{a^4 \cdot b^{-24}\cdot c^{12}}= \frac{b^{8-(-24)}}{a^{4-(-16)} \cdot c^{12-4}}
            = \frac{b^{32}}{a^{20} \cdot c^8}
        \end{aligned} $
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately  `aligned` cannot span across pages.

Comment: @FriendlyGhost: Sure, but is it sensible to break  short answer across pages?

Comment: That is why I stick to `align` rather than `aligned`.

Comment: We could hack `align*` so  that its first row is aligned with the label, but anyway, I'm not sure `\task` can break its content across pages.